# telguarder.com/ scraping with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape telguarder.com for DID status result located in specific CSS selector. And, exactly that selector returns such error. I have tried other selector from the same web page and it retrieves it fine.

```
import bs4, requests, pyperclip
res = requests.get('https://www.telguarder.com/num/00' + pyperclip.paste())
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('#ratingchart > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > svg > g:nth-child(2) > g > g > text')

print(elems[0].text.strip())


Response:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\SCRIPTS\chkspam_debug.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(elems[0].text.strip())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes a number of assumptions, and could be made more robust by checking if a previous step was sucesfull:

```
import bs4
import pyperclip
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.telguarder.com/num/00' + pyperclip.paste())
res.raise_for_status() # make sure you actually good a good response from the server

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('#ratingchart > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > svg > g:nth-child(2) > g > g > text')

if elems:  # did you actually find any elements?
  print(elems[0].text.strip())
else:
  print(f"No ratingchart found for {pyperclip.paste()}")
```

Once all other failure cases are addressed, you can get to to the root of the issue: does that element exist in the response?

```
if "#ratingchart" not in res.text:
    print("No #ratingchart element found in the response")
```

Welcome to the hardest part of web scraping: dynamic javascript pages. Some pages will dynamically load elements once the base page is loaded - as long as your client executes the contained javascript. Your browser does, python's requests module does not. You can confirm this using, eg. `curl`: `curl your_page.com | grep ratingchart`

Scraping dynamic pages requires a javascript engine, which makes the request, allows javascript within the page to run and load dynamic elements, such as the missing `#ratingchart`.

The standard tool for python is selenium. Replace `requests` with `selenium` (easier said than done), and pass `selenium`'s output to `bs4` instead, and, fingers crossed, it should be there. Some web pages can detect that you're using a scraper, however, and won't load properly even using selenium.

Comment: Makes sense. I will try to fidget with selenium, Thanks!